# Should empty <span> tags be avoided from the screenreaders point of view?

Tags: html, usability, screen-readers

Or, what are the implications of having an empty span tag for the visual impaired users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most screen readers should ignore empty `span` elements.

If the empty `span` elements should not be accessed by users, you could give them the WAI-ARIA state [`aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden):

```
<span aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Depending on your use case, HTML5’s [`hidden` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) might be appropriate.